# django objects.filter with 2 conditions for the same keyword where either of them match

Tags: python, django

I wish to filter the queryset to contain objects satisfying either of the 2 conditions. I saw the example where both the conditions are matched, but I wish either of the condition is matched. How do I do it using Q object?
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861678/and-condition-django-query-using-same-keyword)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without more detail into what fields you're matching it's hard to be exact, but basically you want to use the `|` operator to combine two Q objects.

```
from django.db.models import Q
result = SomeModel.objects.filter(Q(somefield='foo') | Q(somefield='bar'))
```

See the docs for full details on Q objects:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Thx a lot http://stackoverflow.com/users/2337736/peter-deglopper. You saved my day !!